# Update: Does Sencha Touch really work with Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I created a simple form based app using Sencha Touch 2.2.0. According to Sencha's website, Sencha Touch should work on Internet Explorer 10. When I double click on the app.html file using Safari, everything works. The same is true for Google Chrome on Windows. When I try the same with Internet Explorer, only the titles of the fieldset appear and no fields are visible. In other words, the form is unusable. I am able to go to Sencha's website and get the Kitchen sink demo working via Internet Explorer but cannot create a project myself that works.

I tried switching to a Windows theme and the form showed some fields but was still unusable.

I was wondering if there's a trick to get a basic Sencha application working with Internet Explorer. I am using Sencha Architect 2.2.2 for this project as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the console log. See if there are any errors there. IE and Chrome/Safari have different tolerance level to some "syntax" errors in JS - for example comma before the closing bracket - IE will not tolerate that.

I also remember there were some issues with simple console.log() under IE which is used widely for trace.

Comment: I ended up starting from scratch and recreating the project. Internet Explorer now works for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your stylesheet:

```
.x-form {
background-color: black !important;
}
```